# rearrange the column and sum row wise

Tags: linux, shell, for-loop, awk

i have a single column text file that contain data with > separator. I just want to rearrange the data and sum row wise.I hope some expert will help me.Thanks in advance.

input

```
>
-5.274285562336444855e-03
-1.159460376948118210e-02
-1.162581238895654678e-02
>
1.672667078673839569e-02
2.755508385598659515e-02
4.910076968371868134e-04
>
1.891197753138840199e-03
-1.517401076853275299e-03
-3.349198959767818451e-03
```

The output should be

```
-5.274285562336444855e-03 + 1.672667078673839569e-02 + 1.891197753138840199e-03
-1.159460376948118210e-02 + 2.755508385598659515e-02 + -1.517401076853275299e-03
-1.162581238895654678e-02 + 4.910076968371868134e-04 + -3.349198959767818451e-03
```

Comment: **"The output should be"** labeled data should be the output expected.

Comment: no sir i need sum of row values

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relatively simple way in `awk` is to concatenate the values in an array using a counter `n` to coordinate the record input and then output in the `END` rule, e.g.

```
awk '$1==">" {n=1; next} {a[n]=a[n](a[n]?" + "$1:$1); sum[n]+=$1;n++} END {for(i=1;i<n;i++) print a[i]" = "sum[i]}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk '$1==">" {n=1; next} {a[n]=a[n](a[n]?" + "$1:$1); sum[n]+=$1;n++} END {for(i=1;i<n;i++) print a[i]" = "sum[i]}' file
-5.274285562336444855e-03 + 1.672667078673839569e-02 + 1.891197753138840199e-03 = 0.0133436
-1.159460376948118210e-02 + 2.755508385598659515e-02 + -1.517401076853275299e-03 = 0.0144431
-1.162581238895654678e-02 + 4.910076968371868134e-04 + -3.349198959767818451e-03 = -0.014484
```

**With Space Instead of `'>'`**

Since in your comment you change the format of the input explaining that `'>'` does not actually appear in the file and that you have empty lines (or lines with a single space -- that isn't clear), you will need to change the conditioning of the 1st rule to `NF==0` instead of `$1==">"`, e.g.

```
$ awk 'NF==0 {n=1; next} {a[n]=a[n](a[n]?" + "$1:$1); sum[n]+=$1;n++} END {for(i=1;i<n;i++) print a[i]" = "sum[i]}' cols2
-5.274285562336444855e-03 + 1.672667078673839569e-02 + 1.891197753138840199e-03 = 0.0133436
-1.159460376948118210e-02 + 2.755508385598659515e-02 + -1.517401076853275299e-03 = 0.0144431
-1.162581238895654678e-02 + 4.910076968371868134e-04 + -3.349198959767818451e-03 = -0.014484
```

(**note:** don't ask for help with text containing `'>'` is your actual text has `' '`. There is no general way the two will be handled the same)

Comment: no i also need sum values not just -5.274285562336444855e-03 + 1.672667078673839569e-02 + 1.891197753138840199e-03
-1.159460376948118210e-02 + 2.755508385598659515e-02 + -1.517401076853275299e-03
-1.162581238895654678e-02 + 4.910076968371868134e-04 + -3.349198959767818451e-03

Comment: if i have blank space in stead of >  will ur script work.can u please suggest what to change for this case

Comment: its not working when i replace > with blank space " "

Comment: (sorry, had a dentist appointment), if the only thing you have is a `space`, then use `NF == 0` instead of `$1==">"`. `awk` doesn't consider whitespace as part of a field.